# LaTeX3 - Check if an argument is empty

Tags: conditionals, expl3, token-lists

What is the best way to translate the following code into `expl3`?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand\test[1]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax EMPTY\else FILLED\fi%
}

\begin{document}

\test{}

\test{OK}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With `\ifcat$\detokenize{#1}$EMPTY\else FILLED\fi` you don't need to rely on `\relax` not being redefined. Maybe its nitpicking. But in the past I stumbled over code written by others where `\relax` was temporaily redefined although processing user-input could take place.

Comment: Thanks. What is the job done by `\ifcat`?

Comment: `\if` compares character codes, `\ifcat` compares category-codes of tokens, both expanding expandable tokens while gathering the next two non-expandable-tokens. Non-expandable control-sequences like `\relax` are assumed with `\if` to have a character-code/with `\ifcat` to have a category-code  which no character-token has. `\relax` is a control-word and therefore could be redefined to yield s.th. like `XX` so that the test `\if\relax...` would always yield the true-branch. `$` cannot be redefined and its catcode in any case differs from catcodes of character-tokens delivered by `\detokenize`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clear answer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is precisely how `\tl_if_empty:nTF` is defined:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\test[1]
  { \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} { EMPTY } { FILLED } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\test{}

\test{OK}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for my not-looking-to-the-doc behavior. :-(

Comment: @projetmbc No problem :)